# Get the ViewContainerRef to which a dynamic component is possibly attached to

Tags: angular

I know that dynamic components can be attached to `ViewContainerRef` by doing this:

```
// assume these vars were previously created, and they have the following types:
// dynamicallyCreatedComponent: ComponentRef
// viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef

viewContainerRef.insert(dynamicallyCreatedComponent.hostView)
```

The thing is, this doesn't seem to work if `dynamicallyCreatedComponent` is attached to another `ViewContainerRef` (it seems to me that `ViewRef`s can only be attached to one `ViewContainerRef` at a time). Therefore, we have to do something like:

```
const indexInOldViewContainer = oldViewContainerRef.indexOf(dynamicallyCreatedComponent.hostView)
oldViewContainerRef.detach(indexInOldViewContainer)
viewContainerRef.insert(dynamicallyCreatedComponent.hostView)
```

**My problem is**: I need to be able to insert the component in the (new) `viewContainerRef`, but I don't have immediate access to `oldViewContainerRef`, which I need to be able to detach from it. It would be great if there were some way of getting it from `ComponentRef`, by doing something like

```
const oldViewContainerRef = dynamicallyCreatedComponent.hostView.enclosingViewContainerRef
```

Does something like this exist?